# Influences of Mozart

Tags: composition, history, mozart

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart#Influence) only mentions [Hummel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Nepomuk_Hummel) from Mozart's childhood but gives no further information.

I will appreciate if someone could shed more light here, in particular which composers have had an influence on Mozart's work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mozart's father, Leopold, was obviously an early influence on the young Wolfgang as his teacher.

JC Bach was a big influence on Mozart. Stanley Sadie in *Mozart: The Early Years* said of JC Bach (in relation to Mozart): "Few composers, Leopold Mozart apart, exercised a comparable influence on the boy or indeed the man."

See http://www.biu.ac.il/hu/mu/min-ad/06-2/8_Bach-Mozart89-104.pdf for a detailed essay on the JC Bach / WA Mozart connection.

Haydn and Mozart had a mutual influence on each other (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haydn_and_Mozart)